# How to place a block inside another one without getChildHtml()

Tags: layout, blocks

I'm working on a loyalty module. For each order, i would like to show the number of loyalty points related to the it in the `sales_order_view`, just below the `order_totals` block, declared in the `sales.xml` layout.

The problem is that i can't modify or override core's templates to avoid any conflict with another module. Therefore, i can't add `getChildHtml()` to place my block.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that for the block you want.
Here is why.
The template `sales/order/view.phtml` renders the `order_items` block through the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_items') ?>`.
This one is rendered by the template `sales/order/items.phtml`.
This other one shows the order totals through `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>`. the totals block is rendered by the template `sales/order/totals.phtml`. 
None of the templates mentioned above have a `getChildHtml()` call without any parameters nor do they allow a generic block where you can add a child block for rendering.

Comment: I noticed that. However, is it possible to use an observer on `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` event to catch `order_totals` block, and then add a child to this block which i could use later in my layout ?

Comment: I don't think that would work either. Attaching a block to the `order_totals` is not a problem. you can do that via layout files. The problem is displaying it. you need an event to attach some html after the main block html is generated. You can try with `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` but not sure that works.

Comment: I previously did that by editing the HTML content of the block's `transportObject` directly in my observer. I felt uncomfortable because it didn't respect the `MVC pattern`. But you gave me an idea : the HTML is now located in a template, and i load it with `toHtml()`. Thanks.

Comment: There are various text lists in several blocks in a given page. One that's always there is for example `before_body_end `. If you can determine what to display without requiring information from a specific block, you can insert it through Javascript and the challenge is reduced to displaying it at the right spot in the page.